# Dealing with multiple font files easier

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I want to import a local font to use in my styles. However, the way it is usually suggested is far from optimal. For a normal, non-variable font, it would take up to 20 `@font-face`, each with up to 5 links for different types inside. That results in having to more or less manually linking up to 100 different files - and only for one font. Imagine amount of effort required when there are multiple fonts in a project.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Will your typefaces/fonts change with each load? If so, then you can create your ```css``` programmatically by building it in a preprocessor. Otherwise, linking 100 different files doesn't really seem that difficult. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Parapluie even if it is just copying first `@font-face` 19 times, it still requires to manually rename remaining 95 file names for them to be linked. And again, this is only for one font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could safely remove some older file types (unless you need the best legacy support):

**Example: "Inter" - generated by [google web font helper](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts)**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('fonts/inter-v11-latin-regular.eot'); 
    src: local(''),
         url('fonts/inter-v11-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('fonts/inter-v11-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), 
         url('fonts/inter-v11-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('fonts/inter-v11-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/inter-v11-latin-regular.svg#Inter') format('svg'); 
  }
```

Could be reduced to:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('fonts/inter-v11-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/inter-v11-latin-regular.woff') format('woff');
  }
```

**woff** should suffice as a fallback for older browsers by now. (Even supported by ie 9 - [see caniuse record](https://caniuse.com/woff)).

**eot** was exclusively used by Microsoft's Internet Explorer. If you're not developing for special cases like windows embedded system applications (depending on custom ie builds) you don't need them.

**svg** only supported by some legacy safari versions - ditch them.

**truetype** Overall probably the best browser support (widely used for desktop applications) but not as optimized for web usage (larger in file size).  Might be needed for tasks like dynamic pdf generation (e.g domPdf or mPdf: most of the time you'll need to manually define embedded fonts at some point)

**local** better remove this rule! Especially firefox had issues displaying local fonts due to [security settings.](https://support.mozilla.org/no/questions/1355994#answer-1455437)

#### CSS preprocessor mixin

As @Parapluie already pointed out you could use a mixin to simplify your css coding.

**SCSS mixin**
based on [@jonathantneal gist](https://gist.github.com/jonathantneal/d0460e5c2d5d7f9bc5e6)

```
@mixin font-face($name, $path, $weight: null, $style: null, $exts: woff2 woff ttf otf) {
    $src: null;
    $formats: (
        otf: "opentype",
        ttf: "truetype"
    );

    @each $ext in $exts {
        $format: if(map-has-key($formats, $ext), map-get($formats, $ext), $ext);
        $src: append($src, url(quote($path + "." + $ext)) format(quote($format)), comma
      );
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: quote($name);
        font-style: $style;
        font-weight: $weight;
        src: $src;
    }
}

@include font-face('Inter', 'fonts/Inter', 400, normal, woff2 woff ttf);
@include font-face('Inter', 'fonts/Inter', 400, italic, woff2 woff ttf);
```

[**Codepen example:**](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/OJvVMbW)
You can switch between compiled/uncompiled css view to see the output.

#### Variable fonts

`font-face` property values accept ranges like e.g for a weight range from 100–900 (light/thin to black).

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100 900;
  src: url('https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/inter/v11/UcC73FwrK3iLTeHuS_fvQtMwCp50KnMa1ZL7W0Q5nw.woff2') format('woff2')
}
```

**SCSS code**

```
@include font-face('Inter VF', 'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/inter/v11/UcC73FwrK3iLTeHuS_fvQtMwCp50KnMa1ZL7W0Q5nw', 100 900, normal, woff2);
```

A presumably more accurate rule would add specific variable font format values like `format('woff2-variations')` and `format('woff2 supports variations')`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100 900;
  src: url('https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/inter/v11/UcC73FwrK3iLTeHuS_fvQtMwCp50KnMa1ZL7W0Q5nw.woff2') format('woff2 supports variations'),
  url('https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/inter/v11/UcC73FwrK3iLTeHuS_fvQtMwCp50KnMa1ZL7W0Q5nw.woff2') format('woff2-variations');
}
```

Unfortunately, these declarations are not yet supported by some browsers and many documentations are outdated due to recent API changes.

So you should still test your rules in different browsers.

#### How to fetch google variable fonts

When using the google fonts UI you might not get the actual variable font .woff2 file.

```
"fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100..900"
```

should work in most modern browsers:
The returned css will contain variable font file URLs

```
"fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900"
```

(generated using the UI) will return seperate font files for each weight.

See also [MDN Docs: Variable fonts guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Fonts/Variable_Fonts_Guide)

Comment: This mixin works like what I need. But can it be modified to accept variable fonts as well?

Comment: @Arctomachine: I've added some details concerning variable fonts. TL:DR I rather recommend to write variable font-face rules manually, since you still need a lot of testing.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal approach: Assuming you have a back-end side, you should generate the style file dynamically, that users can select fonts and weight, or compute used fonts and weights. If all fonts and weight be in the files, browsers will fetch all of the files, except different variation of font file types (e.g. eot)! 20MG or so!